# How to force ExtJs panel keep width when it is hidden

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm having the following issue with extjs panel.

I have a parent panel with hbox layout, and among its children I have another panel with hbox layout. Initially the child panel is hidden, I'm showing it only on some conditions.

The problem is that the width of the hidden child = 0, so it doesn't keep width it has when it is visible. But I need it to have the same width even when it's hidden.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can manually call a `Ext.getCmp('panel_id').doLayout()` on that particular panel. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-doLayout

Answer (score 6):

Instead of calling hide() on the child panel, try this:

```
childPanel.getEl().setOpacity(0); //0 to hide, 1 to show
```

That way the panel is always there, you just control the visibility. It won't mess up your layouts upon hide/show.